# How do you create this jquery slide menu effect?

Tags: javascript, menu, slide

If you go to http://www.rabondigital.com you will see a symbol in the left hand corner of the website. Click the symbol and you will see a slick div slide out. How is this accomplished using javascript or jquery?

Comment: I do it by checking the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site achieves this with jQuery slide effect toggle. Learn more [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/).

*Example (from link above):*
**HTML:**

```
<p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #ccc;" id="toggle"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/SWjh2/).

Comment: Although the link proposes a good solution, it would be super helpful for future visitors if you could include a code snippet demonstrating the plugin, in case the link becomes broken at some point.